# python, ValueError while trying to convert from 12h to 24h time

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a 12h datetime to a 24h datetime. This is my code:

```
_dt = "05/08/2015 1:19 PM"
dt12h = time.strptime(_dt, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
t2 = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S %z', dt12h)
dt = datetime.strptime(t2, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

But I get this error:

`ValueError('unconverted data remains:  ',)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doesn't `dt12h = datetime.strptime(_dt, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")` do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `t2` value has a trailing space, because `%z` is empty (there is no timezone):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> _dt = "05/08/2015 1:19 PM"
>>> dt12h = time.strptime(_dt, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
>>> t2 = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S %z', dt12h)
>>> t2
'08/05/15 13:19:00 '
```

Your `datetime.strptime()` formatter doesn't take this into account.

There is no need to parse, format, then parse again. Just parse directly with `datetime.strptime()` here; `datetime` is perfectly capable of parsing a 12 hour clock time:

```
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(_dt, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 19)
```